# Get the whole embedded document from db

Tags: mongodb-query

I am new to **mongodb**. I have a structure like the below in my DB. I want to get the street1 object using mongodb query.

Can someone help ?

```
"address" : { "street1" : { "dest" : "balanagar"}}.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to above mentioned description, information of street1 key from document  can be retrieved using [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

Example:

`db.collection.find({},{'address.street1':1}`)